# Upload file doesn't neither try to upload

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I have a very simple script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- this is up.php -->
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file">
    <input type="submit">

</form>

<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I select a file and I click on "Submit" the page is istantly reloaded and nothing happens.
I'm trying with this little script because in a more complex page with other fields everything works well except for the file form. I mean, the database is filled with all the informations provided by my form, but images are not uploaded.

The problem is that the page neither try to upload them, I mean, it should upload them (see the percentage on bottom of page) and then pass it to PHP.
In my case instead the page is istantly submitted and reloaded without the attempt of load pictures.

I have other scripts on my server that upload images, and them works.

Why this one does not work? Thanks.

Edit: live demo here:
http://allise.net/up.php

Comment: Got an `Array()` output. Try this `<input type="file[]">`

Comment: Also try naming your submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">`

Comment: 'type="file[]' breaks the input field...

Comment: Actually your `file` needs to be named most probably. Try `<input type="file" name="file">` or whatever is set in your `up.php` file.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Try my suggestion above.

Comment: You mean this ? `<input type="file" name="file">`

Comment: If so, I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your file needs to be named most probably.

Try

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

or whatever is set in your `up.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You need `<form method="post" ...>` for the form to work.

And the file input should have a name attribute.

Comment: Sorry I've updated the script, even with method post set it does not work.